# Mongoose 4.8.1 poolSize won't go above 2

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, mongoose, connection-pooling

For some reason I can't seem to get the poolSize of MongoDB connects to go above 2.

- NodeJS v7.4.0
- Express v4.14.1
- Mongoose v4.8.1

Code example:

```
let database_uri = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/some_database';

let options = {
    server: {
        poolSize: 5
    }
}

mongoose.connect(database_uri, options);
```

The above code will only produce 2 connections. If I set poolSize to 1 it produces 1 connection. If I set it to 2, it produces 2 connections. Anything above 2 only produces 2 connections. All of the documentation I've read says the default is 5 and that you can set this number to anything you want, 10, 15, 500... So any idea why it won't go above 2 for me?

Comment: How are you checking the number of connections?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I apologize, I should have updated this sooner.

*Valeri Karpov* : "More recent versions of the [mongodb driver grow/shrink the connection pool based on usage](https://github.com/mongodb/node-mongodb-native/blob/2.2/HISTORY.md#220-2016-07-05) so the provided poolSize is now treated as the maximum number of connections rather than the actual number of connections."